# Google Colab as a REST endpoint

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

Is it possible to send query parameters via POST or GET to a Google Colab notebook?  (And also have the response be either plaintext or structured json)

- How to retrieve the query in Colab?
- How do you sanitize or suppress the other output so that only plaintext or json is returned to the endpoint call?

Answer (score 2):

You can make direct HTTP requests to the backend from FE Javascript. [Here's an example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=9OyC1_bSEccg).

Reproducing the key bits:

> A webserver can be started on the kernel to serve up arbitrary
>   resources.
>
> The client needs to reference the resource with
>   `https://localhost:{port}` but this will automatically be translated
>   to `http://localhost:{port}`.
>
> By default responses will be cached in the notebook for offline
>   access.

Comment: is there a way to access it via a URL, i.e. endpoint access from an arbitrary mobile app

Comment: No. By design, Colab backends are not accessible outside of Colab.

Comment: Using `ngrok` can make it accessible publicly. But it's probably not encouraged to be used.